# Why are some buttons on the website not working?

Tags: html

I'm new to coding and recently developed a website but it has some issues. Some of them are buttons that do not work entirely. To do the buttons I used a `<a>` tag so people were led to a different page when clicking on them. The weird thing is that I used the same code for all of them ( `<a class="connect-button" href="./contact.html">Inquire</a>`for example) and some of them work and others don't. Here is the website https://giacomosorbi.github.io/joanaoli09-module-i/index.html

So for example, in this part of the home page, the right and left button work and the middle one doesn't even thought they all have the exact same code:

[image]

```html
<h3 class="services-title">
                    Content <br />
                    Creation
                  </h3>
                  <div class="services-text">
                      Based on your project requirements, I’ll create/recreate the identity for your business and provide a wide range of content for you to use on different platforms as well as advise you on how to implement it. 
                  </div>
                  <div class="moreinfo-button">
                    <a href="./work.html">Know more</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <div class="second-column">
                  <h3 class="services-title">
                    Strategy <br />
                    Session
                  </h3>
                  <div class="services-text">
                      You can book a strategy session with me so we can discuss your ideas and goals for your business. Similar sessions will repeat multiple times during the process of development of your Brand. Feel free to contact me if you would like to meet with me!
                  </div>
                  <div class="moreinfo-button">
                    <a href="./work.html">Know more</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <div class="third-column">
                  <h3 class="services-title">
                    Brand <br />
                    Design
                  </h3>
                  <div class="services-text">
                      I’ll design and develop the identity of your brand based on your requirements and the briefing and strategy meetings. This will be a continuous process of ongoing communication between me and you. 
                  </div>
                  <div class="moreinfo-button">
                    <a href="./work.html">Know more</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The same happens with a few more buttons throughout the website like the "Learn more" button and "Inquire" button at the end of the home page as well as a few more in the other pages.

Here you can see all of the code: https://github.com/GiacomoSorbi/joanaoli09-module-i

Comment: When you inspect your markup you can see, that the elements `.what-i-do` and `.connect-title` are overlapping your middle button, that is why you can't click on them. So you would need to change these vertical texts are styled

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your css for these two classes `.what-i-do` and `.connect-title` to the following all `<a>` tags should work.

```css
.what-i-do {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.connect-title {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: @JoanaOliveira Good to hear and glad that I was able to help you. Thanks